# Mouseover tag information is incorrect on Meta

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tagging

The mouseover information for tags included with the `[tag:...]` syntax on Meta is not pulled from the main site. For example [tikz-pgf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf) should have a tag wiki excerpt and one subscriber. Also the “Help us edit this wiki” link goes to the tag wiki on meta, not on the main site.

Comment: So is the suggestion here to have mouse-overs on meta sites to incorporate that of meta & main (since meta has its own set of tags)?

Answer (score 9):

Markdown tagging seems to be site-specific, even across the main-and-meta components. While the same holds on [Meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) - where the separation between main-and-meta is more apparent since each has their own reputation system - a generic network-wide setup is probably why it works this way. Another motivation behind this site-specific tag markdown is that it may be possible (in general) to have duplicate tags across the two components, however unlikely. As an example, consider

- Main: [scope](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope) - referencing "the context within which a variable name or other identifier is valid and can be used, or within which a declaration has effect"; and
- Meta: [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) - referencing whether questions are on- or off-topic

or perhaps

- Main: [mwe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mwe) - about the [`mwe` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/mwe), which helps in the creation of Minimal Working Examples; and
- Meta: [mwe](/questions/tagged/mwe) - an abbreviation for Minimal Working Example. This means the reduction of code to the core idea, which is still compilable.

The distinction may be more apparent in some cases, but in general the separation is perfectly justifiable.

Note that there is meta- and main-specific markdown for tagging (see [Proper tags using markdown](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3521/5764)):

- Main: `[tag:<tag>]`
- Meta: `[meta-tag:<tag>]`