# Proper tags using markdown

Tags: support, markdown

In discussions on meta, I sometimes want to reference a specific tag. Instead of just writing {support} (as in `{support}`) to resemble the tag notation, I write it as a hyperlink [{support}](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support). Is this the best way, or is there some other way to write proper hyperlinked tags using markdown?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Markdown does offer proper hyperlinked tags using a specific syntax. For example, the tag `<tag>` on the main site can set in markdown using `[tag:<tag>]`, while the same tag on meta would be `[meta-tag:<tag>]`. Markdown syntax for tagging is recommended, since it provides the appropriate formatting associated with each tag. For example, see

- {support} | [{support}](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support) | [support](/questions/tagged/support); or
- {faq} | [{faq}](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) | [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)

This markdown syntax does not perform checks on the existence of tags. However, this should come as no [surprise](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/surprise).

Comment: Ah maybe `<tag>` is the way to include tags in wiki excerpts

Comment: @percusse: My approach is to use `{<tag>}` to excerpts and `[tag:<tag>]` for wikis. The former is not hyperlinked, because excerpts are window flyouts that do not support hyperlinks. Wikis do and therefore can benefit from the recommended markdown.